# Can I use cluster replication for Hbase migration between two different clusters?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, mapr

I am planning to migrate between two different clusters where i am required to copy the Hbase table from old cluster to the new cluster, can cluster replication mechanism which is widely used for backing up data be used for the copying Hbase table from old cluster to the new cluster.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this with cluster replication. I have only tested this with MapR. You can find information about replication here:

http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Configuring+MapR+Clusters+for+Replication+Between+Tables

Which distribution are you using, if you are using MapR you can also use the replication at the file system level for DR, as documented here:
- http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Data+Protection#DataProtection-Solution:MirroringtoAnotherCluster

(Disclaimer: I am working for MapR)